# Getting NPE while trying to make screenshot in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, ui-automation

I've tried various things, but still getting the NPE. Please see the code snippets below.

**TestBase.class**

```
public WebDriver initializeDriver() { // nothing special }

public void takeScreenshot(String testResult) {
    try {
      File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
      FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File(
        "//Users//roman//Desktop//MainProject//SeleniumJava//ScreenshotsFailure//"
        + testResult + "_" + "screenshot.png"));

      //
      // System.getProperty("user.dir")

      log.info("Screenshot of " + testResult + "'s failure has been created successfully");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      log.error("Screenshot of " + testResult + "'s failure has not been created");
    }
  }
```

**Listeners.class**

```
public class Listeners implements ITestListener {
  TestBase testBase = new TestBase();
  Date currentDate;

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        currentDate = new Date();
        testBase.takeScreenshot(iTestResult.getName() + "_" + currentDate.getTime());
  }
```

**HomePageTest.class**

```
          @Test
          void my() {
            Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "adb"); 
// intentionally cause False to take a screenshot of this failure
          }
```

So the NPE occurs is these two lines:

```
  File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

and

```
testBase.takeScreenshot(iTestResult.getName() + "_" + currentDate.getTime());
```

How can this be fixed?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NPE cannot occur in two lines. There is always exactly one line which throws the exception. Print and show the stack trace of your exception.

I assume that `driver` and `iTestResult` or `currentDate` is null, for whatever reason. You may insert a log message to print out their values before they get used.

You may also insert line breaks, then the stack trace will tell you exactly which part has the null pointer:

```
testBase.takeScreenshot(
      iTestResult.getName() + "_" + 
      currentDate.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Stefan! 
I did like you said - put the log msg and the driver is null at the screenshot taking moment, here
  File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

I put the 'static' for driver variable in TestBase and it helped! But I heard about various cons about static driver (concurrent execution is particular). Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I do not know if using static driver is a bad idea. I would check the documentation of that class and if there is no such note, then just do it.